# Delete Command on GridPanel Need Confirmation

Tags: ext.net

Hello i want to know how to let the user confirm before deleting Item on Grid Panel so if the user clicked no should stop deleting if yes will fire the ajaxevent.
this is my code but it dose not work .

```
<script>
var showResult = function (btn) {
var bsit = false;
Ext.Msg.confirm('Delete!', 'Are You Sure?', function (btn, text) {
if (btn == 'yes') {
bsit = true;
} else {
bsit = false;
}
});
retrn bsit;
};

</script>
```

and this is the gridpanel

```
<ext:GridPanel Title="Emplyees" AnimCollapse="true" ID="GridPanel1" runat="server" Width="700"
StoreID="grvContractors">
<ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel1" runat="server">
<Columns>
<ext:Column ColumnID="Name" Header="Name" Width="150" Sortable="true"
DataIndex="Contractor_Name">
</ext:Column>
<ext:Column ColumnID="Tel" Header="Phone" DataIndex="Tel" Width="150" Sortable="true">
</ext:Column>
<ext:CommandColumn Width="60">
<Commands>
<ext:GridCommand Icon="Delete" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" >
</ext:GridCommand>
</Commands>
</ext:CommandColumn>
</Columns>
</ColumnModel>
<SelectionModel>
<ext:RowSelectionModel ID="RowSelectionModel1" runat="server" />
</SelectionModel>
<Listeners>
<Command Handler="showResult" />
</Listeners>
<AjaxEvents>
<Command OnEvent="DeleteVote" >
<ExtraParams>
<ext:Parameter Name="Contractor_ID" Value="record.data.Contractor_ID" Mode="Raw" />
</ExtraParams>
</Command>
</AjaxEvents>
</ext:GridPanel>
```

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: What version of Ext.NET do you use?

Comment: Coolite  Version 0.8.2.2648 , i know there is a new until versions 3.2.1 but for some reasons i can't update right now to the new version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure suitable for you  as u using older version,I generaly doing that like this;
v.2.2

```
<ext:CommandColumn runat="server">
                  <Commands>
                      <ext:GridCommand Icon="Delete" CommandName="delete"  >
                      </ext:GridCommand>
                  </Commands>
                   <Listeners >
                    <Command  Handler=" if(showResult()){App.direct.Test(); } else{ } "></Command> 

                   </Listeners>

               </ext:CommandColumn>
```